# Body and header text flickering while social media plugins load

Tags: wordpress, twitter, facebook-social-plugins, disqus, facebook-comments

I've placed a number of social media plugins in our blog templates:

- Facebook like
- Tweet
- Google +1
- FB Comments
- Disqus Comments

While these modules load, I'm getting a flickering effect on all text, including H and P tags. Anyone have an idea as to what's causing this / possible remedy?

The page in question can be found here:

http://www.windycitywebsites.com/developing-a-navigational-structure-that-works-for-visitors-and-crawlers-alike/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is FOUC.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Try the techniques listed here:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content

Comment: It's not the flash of unstyled content that's the problem. Resolved that by using Typekit's .wf-inactive / .wf-active class identifiers and proper CSS structure. But I'm still getting the flashing content when the page is loaded. The style itself isn't changing... but the elements entirely are just flashing... disappearing for a split second and reappearing. Not an optimal situation. It seems to have something specifically to do with the social media elements, as this is not happening on any page that does not contain them (i.e. what we do, what we've done, etc).

Comment: ok, do this.  Remove every piece of css and every reference to css files from the page and load it.  Does it flash?  probably not.  Start adding back in css one by one until it starts. Then follow the techniques for optimize css loading and position within the page load (lots of article out hter on the subject).